# How do I make the bot send only 2 periods of time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So simply i want to make my bot say : **If the text have week specified, Then It'll send weeks and days remaining, If it has days, Then it'll send the days and hours remaining. Example:**

Time remaining : 2 weeks, 3 days
Time remaining : 1 day, 5 hours

The part of the code that has the weeks, Minutes, Hours, Seconds :

```js
  let gwTime = ms(time);
  let timeRemain = gwTime 
  weeks = Math.floor((timeRemain / (24*60*60*1000))/7);
  weeksms = Math.floor((timeRemain % (24*60*60*1000))/7);
days = Math.floor(weeksms / (24*60*60*1000));
daysms = weeksms % (24*60*60*1000);
hours = Math.floor(daysms / (60*60*1000));
hoursms = timeRemain % (60*60*1000);
minutes = Math.floor(hoursms / (60*1000));
minutesms = timeRemain % (60*1000);
sec = Math.floor(minutesms / 1000);
// weeks = Math.floor(days / 7);
  let gwEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  
    .setTitle(`${prize}`)

 //  .setDescription(`**Time Remaining**${weeks} weeks ${days} days
 //  .setDescription(`**Hosted By**`)
 // ${hours} hours ${minutes} minutes ${sec} seconds`)

    .addField('**Time Remaining: **', `${weeks} weeks ${days} days
 ${hours} hours ${minutes} minutes ${sec} seconds`, true)
  
    .addField('**Hosted By**', `<@965460337275064351>`, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what's the way for the message from the bot to be triggered so I assumed the bot will send a message that your code showed while executing a command.

You can use the if statement to determine whether the value is true or false, and check if it has an actual value either. To make it visualise, I will show it in code.

```js
var No = 0;

if (!No) console.log('No Number')
```

In this situation, `No` is passing into the negative option of the conditional statement as the value of it is `0`. Therefore, you will see 'No Number' in the console.

Back to your question, you can apply the if statements to check if there are weeks in remain or days either.

```js
if (weeks) { // Have at least 1 week
    gwEmbed.addField('**Time Remaining: **', `${weeks} weeks ${days} days`, true)
} else if (days) { // Have at least 1 day
    gwEmbed.addField('**Time Remaining: **', `${days} days ${hours} hours`, true)
} else { // No week, No day

}
```

Besides your question, I doubt there are some bugs in the time converting code. I would recommend you use the variable separately. For instants, consider using `timeRemain` for every ms variable instead of using the upper one and making it chain.

---

For your references, here is the If statement Documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else